# Serialize Multiple Objects in the Same File (Windows Store App)

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to serialize my objects in a Windows Store apps project, but i can't find the best way to do it. I was planning to serialize multiple objects in one single file. Is it possible?

Comment: Check out https://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just create a document (xml or a json object) with multiple children, each a string representing a serialized object. One way to do it would be to create a `Dictionary<string, object>` where each object has a unique name.